# How can I regain the ability to output to an external monitor via HDMI on my Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro?

Tags: windows-8.1, hdmi, external-display, intel-graphics, lenovo-laptop

I've had a Yoga 2 Pro (running 64-bit Windows 8.1) for a few months.  I usually have it hooked up to an external monitor via HDMI.  I disconnect and reconnect it all the time.  This machine has the Intel 4000 onboard graphics.

All of a sudden today, it no longer recognizes that an external display is connected.  It could be related to an automatic Windows update that was performed while it was disconnected.  Here are some details of symptoms and what I've tried:

- I tried uninstalling the display drivers and reinstalling the version from Lenovo's site
- Normally I would right-click on the desktop, select Graphics Options, then "Output To", and I'd have a number of options.  But now the "Output to" menu is completely gone.
- I've tried with another monitor (my TV).  As soon as I connected it, the TV recognized that something was hooked up (i.e. it gave me a message "something is hooked up on HDMI2" - but when I switch the input there, there is no signal).

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is the right place to ask a question like this, but you're not alone;  I'm having the same issue with a new Lenovo U430 Touch with Intel HD 4400.  The monitor is "sort of" detected, but doesn't get any input.  I've tried two versions of the drivers from Lenovo's website.

Comment: You may find [Windows 8.1 Doesn't Recognize External Monitor](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-hardware/windows-81-doesnt-recognize-external-monitor/daf55e9c-acf5-4425-8026-a86a23a3ccec) helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with lenovo yoga 2 11. Sudenly just when I blend it as tablet with the hdmi cable connected it detects the external monitor. Then I realized that it was a physical problem with the hdmi connector. try to move the cable on cable or adapter you have.

Answer (score 0):

I found a wonderful set of instructions and ideas that gave me a good hint in

https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Idea-Windows-based-Tablets-and/Yoga-13-Video/m-p/1272851#M8030

I hope you get out of the mud soon

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link, as the answer can become invalid if the linked page changes or the target site is unreachable/permanently offline.